# DIV's Width & Height CSS style same as its container table column

Tags: css

I would like set a div's width & height values to be the same as a table's cell automatically.

Table column `<td>` will be dynamic width & height.

> Purpose : User have to click each cell of table.

Let's say,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <-------- dynamic width & height
      <commandLink>
        <div> <---------- I cannot click this <div> as link, can you provide me?
          //nod ata
        </div>
      </commandlink>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply

```
td div {
   width: 100%;
   height : 100%;
}
```

but you will need to specify a height for the `td` element.

Anyway by default a div is already fitting the whole width so `height: 100%` is enough.

If your div has to be clickable either you append a `<a>` tag inside the div with the following style

```
td div#your-id a {
   display : block;
   width: 100%;
   height : 100%;
}
```

or you attach an handler for `onclick` event to the div via JavaScript.

Comment: <td> <-------- dynamic width & hight
     <commandLink>
     <div> <---------- I cannot click shit <div>  as link, cau provide me?
      //nod ata
     </div>
     </comandlink>
    </td>

Comment: it will be effect the whole project. if div have `id` what I change this style?